# MongoDB count very slow

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a collection with 1.5 million documents. I'm counting using PHP:

```
$db->some->ensureIndex(array("sometext" => 1));
$db->some->ensureIndex(array("datsbla" => 1));
$arr["sometext"] = $string; 
$arr["datsbla"] = array('$gte' => $some, '$lte' => $thing);
$count = $db->some->count($arr);
```

I turned on the profiler and every count like that is like 4500 ms. I have 20 counters like that in my page, so it makes my web page VERY VERY SLOW.

What should I do to make it faster (< 100 ms) ? Is it even possible using MongoDB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate individual indexes - a query can only use 1 index at a time, so you are not taking advantage of the indexing fully.  Try a compound index on both fields and you should see a significant improvement.

Comment: This is the most important problem. You'll need an index {sometext:1, datsbla:1} to make this fast. If you really can't only make an index on the highest cardinality field, but not both. +1